# How can I pass a command to data.table::fread() function using a cmd argument when the script contains a combination of single and double quotes?

Tags: r, shell, data.table

I have a zipped folder that contains a number of csv files. I am reading them using `data.table::fread()` function. I need to preprocess the files before reading them in using the following example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450810/substitute-every-comma-outside-of-double-quotes-for-a-pipe because some fields contain commas within double quotes which causes an error. I am replacing all commas that are outside quotation marks with pipes then reading my files as pipe delimited. Here is my code:

```
df <- fread(cmd = "unzip -p -a myfolder.zip | sed -Ee :1 -e 's/^(([^",]|"[^"]*")*),/\1|/;t1'",
      sep = "|",
      header = TRUE,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      quote = "",
      fill = TRUE)
```

Now the above code would clearly not work because I am using double quotes around a script that contains both single and double quotes. I am using `R 3.6.0` and `data.table 1.12.8`. What is the workaround for this scenario? Thank you.

Comment: You can use "raw character constants". See the `?Quotes` help page for example. This makes it easier to mix nested quotes. So `cmd = r"(unzip -p -a myfolder.zip | sed -Ee :1 -e 's/^(([^",]|"[^"]*")*),/\1|/;t1')"`

Comment: @MrFlick, unfortunately that solution is not going to work for versions that are earlier than `R 4.0.0`. As noted, the version I have is `R 3.6.0`.

Comment: Then just escape your nested double quotes with a slash. `cmd = "unzip -p -a myfolder.zip | sed -Ee :1 -e 's/^(([^\",]|\"[^\"]*\")*),/\1|/;t1'"`

Comment: @MrFlick I am getting: `sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Error in fread(cmd = "unzip -p -a file.zip | sed -Ee :1 -e 's/^(([^\",]|\"[^\"]*\")*),/\001|/;t1",  :
  File '/tmp/xxxxxx/filexxxxxx' does not exist or is non-readable. getwd()=='/dir/dir/dir'`.

Comment: Can you provide any sort of input and desired output that can be used for testing? You have verified the command works at the command line?

Comment: @MrFlick, yes, the command on its own works in `bash`. I will work on a test data. Thank you. I was hoping for an  `R`or `shell` workaround. Possibly a way to not use the single quotations in the `shell` script?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the `shell` script to remove commas embedded within double quotation marks. I do not need them. Here is the inspiration: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48672/only-remove-commas-embedded-within-quotes-in-a-comma-delimited-file. I was still getting `...unrecognized escape in character string...` error. I then escaped all escape characters and the script worked. Here is what I ended up with:

```
cmd = "unzip -p -a myfolder.zip | sed ':a;s/^\\(\\([^\"]*,\\?\\|\"[^\",]*\",\\?\\)*\"[^\",]*\\),/\1 /;ta'"
 
removeQuotes <- function(x) gsub("\"", "", x)
dff <- fread(cmd = cmd,
             sep=",",
             header = TRUE,
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE,      
             quote = "",
             fill=TRUE) %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, removeQuotes)
```

Thanks everyone for your help!